# Creating XPS documents with multiple page sizes

Tags: .net, wpf, xps

I'm creating XPS files from XAML elements. More than that, I'm creating XPS files where each page might be a different size. See this minimal reproduction:

```
using (Package pkg = Package.Open("out.xps", FileMode.Create))
using (XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(pkg))
{
    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
    SerializerWriterCollator collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();

    WritePage(816, 1344); // 8.5 x 14
    WritePage(816, 1056); // 8.5 x 11
    WritePage(816, 1344);
    WritePage(816, 1056);

    collator.EndBatchWrite();

    doc.Close();
    pkg.Close();

    void WritePage(double width, double height)
    {
        var element = new Border()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(10.0)
        };

        Size size = new Size(width, height);
        element.Measure(size);
        element.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        element.UpdateLayout();

        collator.Write(element);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that all my pages end up being the same size. Or more correctly, the same size as the first page. The pages for that document all show as:

```
<FixedPage ... Width="816" Height="1344">
```

My first try at fixing this was to set a `PrintTicket` when I write -- but it has no effect.

Some debugging later and I've traced the issue down to the WPF method `XpsSerializationManager.SaveAsXml`:

```
if (this._simulator == null)
{
    this._simulator = new ReachHierarchySimulator(
        (PackageSerializationManager) this, serializedObject);
}

...

if (this._isBatchMode)
{
    xmlWriter = this._simulator.SimulateBeginFixedPage();
}
```

Here, it is initializing `_simulator` only on the first call to `SaveAsXml`. Stored within the simulator is `serializedObject` -- the `Visual` we're trying to save. Problem is, this reference sticks around for subsequent calls.

Next, it calls `_simulator.SimulateBeginFixedPage` to create that first `<FixedPage>` element -- but because it has a reference to the original object, each page gets the same size as that object.

So the workaround I've made is to update that reference via reflection prior to every `Write` call:

```
void WritePage(double width, double height)
{
    var element = new Border()
    {
        Width = width,
        Height = height,
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(10.0),
        Tag = pageCounter++
    };

    object manager = collator.GetType()
        .GetField("_manager", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        ?.GetValue(collator);

    object simulator = manager?.GetType()
        .GetField("_simulator", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        ?.GetValue(manager);

    simulator?.GetType()
        .GetField("_serializedObject", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .SetValue(simulator, element);

    Size size = new Size(width, height);
    element.Measure(size);
    element.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    element.UpdateLayout();

    collator.Write(element);
}
```

But -- I feel like this is too weird and probably an issue in my usage of WPF rather than a bug in WPF itself. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just to let you know. I see you are missing collator.BeginBatchWrite();